# Question about adverbs taking と

Tags: grammar

I read the definition for the noun 雑用.

> いろいろのこまごまとした用事。

I understand that the と particle here is modifying the verb する. So my question is if parsing the sentence like this is correct:

> ((いろいろのこまごま)と(した))(用事)。

My question is what type of adverb would いろいろのこまごま be? Maybe my parsing of the sentence is wrong?

Comment: {(いろいろの)|(こまごまとした)}用事. Related: [Difference between 青々とした and 青々した?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25460/43676), [Meaning of (と)した in やんわりとした暖房](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74965/43676)

Comment: Kind of related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/87610/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's parsed like `いろいろの(こまごまとした用事)`.

[こまごま(と)](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%B4%B0%E3%80%85) is an *adverb*, and thus it cannot be directly modified by いろいろの ("various"). いろいろのこまごま makes no sense when isolated like this. Here, こまごまとした modifies 用事 first, forming a noun phrase:

- 用事 things to do
- こまごまとした用事 miscellaneous things to do

Check this question to see what this とした is doing: [Meaning of (と)した in やんわりとした暖房](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74965/5010)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!